# Substring before first uppecase word excluding first word

Tags: sql, postgresql, substring, regexp-like

String contains words separated by spaces.

How to get substring from start until first uppercase word (uppercase word excluded)? If string start with uppercase, this word should included. Search should start from secord word. First word should always appear in result.

For example

```
select substringtiluppercase('Aaa b cC Dfff dfgdf')
```

should return

```
Aaa b cC
```

Can regexp substring used or other idea?

Using PostgreSQL 13.2

Uppercase letters are latin letters A .. Z and additionally Õ, Ä, Ö , Ü, Š, Ž

Comment: Is it possible for the first uppercase word to be the first word?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Removal should start from second word. I updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace everything from a leading word boundary then an uppercase letter onwards with blank:

```
regexp_replace('aaa b cc Dfff dfgdf', '(?<!^)\m[A-ZÕÄÖÜŠŽ].*', '')
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/99501).

In Postgres flavour of regex, `\m` "word boundary at the beginning of a word".

`(?<!^)` is a negative look behind asserting that the match is not preceded by start of input.

fyi the other Postgres word boundaries are `\M` at end of a word, `\y` either end (same as usual `\b`) and `\Y` not a word boundary (same as usual `\B`).

Comment: Question was not clear. Removal should start from second word. If string starts with upper case, first word should appear in result. I updated question. How to start removal from second word?

Comment: @Andrus Solved. See edit to answer.

Comment: Thank you. Great. How to add exception that that word **T-shirt** is included in result? Eq __Product T-shirt long Adidas__ should return **Product T-shirt long** ?

Comment: That would be changing the nature of the question, which would invalidate current answers. Please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: I posted new question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74709269/how-get-name-before-first-uppercase-word-excluding-t-shirt

Answer (score 1):

Sunstring supprts Regular expüression in Postgres

```
SELECT substring('aaa b cc Dfff dfgdf' from '^[^A-ZÕÄÖÜŠŽ]*')
```

| substring |
| --- |
| aaa b cc |

> ```
> SELECT 1
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/C52KYbN3)

```
SELECT 
reverse(substr(reverse(substring('aaa b ccD Dfff dfgdf' from '.*\s[A-ZÕÄÖÜŠŽ]')),2))
```

| reverse |
| --- |
| aaa b ccD |

> ```
> SELECT 1
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1cJldE8X)

Comment: This returs wrong result if uppercase character is after first charader in word. `SELECT substring('aaa b cD Dfff dfgdf' from '^[^A-ZÕÄÖÜŠŽ]*')`   returns `aaa b c`  but should return `aaa b cD`. How to fix it?

Comment: then you need to change it a bit, but as you add more and more conditions you will get more and more complexity

Comment: Question was not clear. Removal should start from second word. If string starts with upper case, first word should appear in result. I updated question. How to start removal from second word?

Comment: my query does exactly what you wanted, even with the the new string https://dbfiddle.uk/lIQlIcGK

Comment: How to add exception that that word T-shirt is included in result? Eq Product T-shirt Adidas should return Product T-shirt?

Comment: you can't raise an exception in sql, you can do this only procdures, you can always check if the result has a position > 0 for t-shirt

Comment: I want simply that word T-shirt will appear in result also. How to change your query so word T-shirt will not break result but other words staring uppercase will break? I dont want to raise any exception, only change result.

Comment: @Andrus my query does exact what you want https://dbfiddle.uk/ldBdKhG3

Comment: It returs worng result for Product Tshirt Adidas . It should return Product in this case. I posted this as separate question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74709269/how-get-name-before-first-uppercase-word-excluding-t-shirt