# How get name before first uppercase word excluding T-shirt

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, substring, regexp-replace

Products have names like

```
Product one white Adidas
Other product black Hill sheet
Nice T-shirt blue Brower company
```

How to get starting part of product name before first uppercase word starting from second word and up to first uppercase word excluding word T-shirt.
Result from strings above should be

```
Product one white
Other product black
Nice T-shirt blue
```

Using Bohemian answer to question

[Substring before first uppecase word excluding first word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74670361/substring-before-first-uppecase-word-excluding-first-word)

```
regexp_replace('Nice T-shirt blue Brower company', '(?<!^)\m[A-ZÕÄÖÜŠŽ].*', '')
```

returns wrong result

```
Nice
```

How to modify regex so that it returns

```
Nice T-shirt blue
```

Using Postgres 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative look ahead:

```
select regexp_replace('Nice T-shirt blue Brower company', '(?<!^)\m(?!T-shirt)[A-ZÕÄÖÜŠŽ].*', '')
```

See [live demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5BfvRhcUwVTA5YQN1j2q61/0).

`(?!T-shirt)` means *the following characters must not be 'T-shirt'*

You can add other capitalised terms to ignore:

```
(?!T-shirt|BB gun|BBQ tongs)
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex works for your test cases:

`^[A-Z][a-z ]*(T-shirt)?[a-z ]*`

Explanation:

`^`: Start of line

`[A-Z]`: Any capital letter

`[a-z ]*`: zero or more characters that are either a lowercase letter or space

`(T-shirt)?`: The phrase `T-shirt` 0 or 1 times

`[a-z ]*`: same again

Comment: I added national letters to regex:  ^[A-ZÕÄÖÜŠŽ][a-zõäöüšž ]*(T-shirt)?[a-zõäöüšž ]* . Is this ok? Words may contain also some other characters like - / and + . Should all possible characters listed separately in regex?

Comment: Please test on your data, and make another comment if it doesn't work. It's difficult to fix issues when 1, I don't know if it's a problem in the first place, and 2, I don't have sample inputs to check.

Comment: regexp_replace('Shoes Attalla', '^[A-Z][a-z ]*(T-shirt)?[a-z ]*', '') returns **Attalla** but should return Shoes. It looks like this is totally wrong.

Comment: That's because you haven't applied the `regexp_replace` correctly. The regex I've provided selects the part of the next you want to keep, not the text to be removed. To fix that, run `regexp_replace('Shoes Attalla', '^([A-Z][a-z ]*(T-shirt)?[a-z ]*).*$', '$1')`. (To briefly explain, capture the part you need to keep, and use `.*$` to consume the rest of the line. Then just replace with the first capture group)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a direct match, you can simply remove the part of the string (in this case from the last uppercase word to the end) that you do not need:

```
select regexp_replace(name, '(?<=\s)[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z\s]+$', '') from tbl
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/loj3lu_A).

Comment: This returns wrong result if there are no oper uppercase words. For Nice T-shirt blue brower company it returns Nice but correct result is whole string Nice T-shirt blue brower company

Comment: It returns incorrect result for Product ONE white Adidas. Correct result is **Product** but it returns **Product ONE white**

Comment: @Andrus Please see my recent edit. Also, as dc-ddfe pointed out, consider posting your *all* your sample inputs.